# TeX document won't read Latin characters

Tags: fonts, compiling, font-encodings

I'm using TexWorks to write a document, but everytime I open my document some characters aren't read, and the result is this:

[image: My Tex document.]

How can I solve this problem?

Ps: The language I'm using is portuguese.

Comment: it is hard to tell from an image which encoding that is, but make sure that you save the file in UTF-8 encoding from your editor and then add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to declare that encoding to latex

Comment: The source code shows unknown characters (a question mark in a black diamond) so your source code file encoding is corrupt. The status bar at the bottom shows "UTF-8" but it apparently isn't a UTF-8 file.